# Глубокое клонирование в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Какие есть способы глубокого клонирования объектов в JavaScript?

Comment: 100% дубликат  ..

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: @Дмытрык, это не для всех obj сработает

Comment: @Grundy - я знаю. Но это один из способов)